# install Active Directory module powershell for windows 10

Tags: powershell, powershell-module

Good afternoon!
I need to add only the module rsat Active Directory module powershell in windows 10
Execute command:
    Enable-WindowsOptionalFeature -Online -FeatureName RSATClient-Roles-AD-Powershell
But error:

```
Enable-WindowsOptionalFeature : Не удается прочитать параметр реестра.(Can not read the registry entry.)
строка:1 знак:1
+ Enable-WindowsOptionalFeature -Online -FeatureName RSATClient-Roles-A ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Enable-WindowsOptionalFeature], COMException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.Dism.Commands.EnableWindowsOptionalFeatureCommand
```

If to apply parameter -All, all components are installed.
How to solve a problem?

Comment: assuming that you have russian windows you may try to ask your question on a russian SO: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/

Answer (score 2):

These instructions are for Windows 7; the process will likely be similar for Windows 10.

1. First, find and install the *Remote Server Administration Tools (RSAT)* update package for your version of Windows. [I found this easily](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=RSAT+Windows+7&t=ffab&ia=web).
2. Then, you'll need to enable the feature once it is installed.

   1. Go to Control Panel -> Programs and Features -> Turn Windows features on or off (or, open it directly, from the command line: `%windir%\System32\OptionalFeatures.exe`
   2. Find Remote Server Adminstration Tools -> Role Adiminstration Tools -> AD DS and AD LDS Tools -> Active Directory Module for Windows PowerShell, and turn it on

      [image: Windows Features]
   3. You may need to restart your computer. I don't recall.
3. Finally, import the module, and use it normally.

Answer (score 1):

At the top of your PowerShell script you just need to include the following.

```
Import-Module activedirectory
```

Assuming you have the RSAT tools already installed on the Win10 machines via Control Panel.

Comment: Rsat has been install.

Answer (score 0):

To install ActiveDirectory powershell module in Windows 10, you need to install RSAT. (Remote Server Administration Tools)

Achieve it with:

Settings (win + i) -> Apps -> Optional features -> Add a feature -> Select "RSAT: Active Directory Domain Services and Lightweight Directory Services Tools" -> Install

[image: add an optional feature interface]

After it `Import-Module ActiveDirectory` will work in powershell.